# Dell E6500 wireless not working after fresh installation of ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04

I had made a fresh installation of ubuntu 12.04. After the installation, the wireless is not working. In rare of the rare case it shows sometime the wireless available with very low frequency. This happens when I keep my laptop and mode very next to it. I verified that it is working fine with Windows XP (a different laptop with me).

Kindly help me I very frustrated with this new release and is fighting for the resolution since last 1 week.

Below is the list of codes I had run in the terminal after google.com help. This might be helpful for resolving my issue.

================================================================

```
cat /etc/lsb-release; uname -a
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04 LTS"
Linux Chunmun 3.2.0-27-generic-pae #43-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 6 15:06:05 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux


nprakash@Chunmun:~$  lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82567LM Gigabit Network Connection [8086:10f5] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:024f]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e

0c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Ultimate N WiFi Link 5300 [8086:4235]
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:1121]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

### lsusb

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0c45:63f0 Microdia 
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 0a5c:5801 Broadcom Corp. BCM5880 Secure Applications Processor with fingerprint swipe sensor
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 413c:8157 Dell Computer Corp. Integrated Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 008: ID 413c:8158 Dell Computer Corp. Integrated Touchpad / Trackstick
Bus 003 Device 009: ID 413c:8156 Dell Computer Corp. Wireless 370 Bluetooth Mini-card
```

================================================================

```
iwconfig

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:"ghar"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 80:A1:D7:7C:30:50   
      Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
      Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality=29/70  Signal level=-81 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:5  Invalid misc:1117   Missed beacon:0

eth0      no wireless extensions.


rfkill list

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Perhaps the card is broken. How did you check it with another laptop?

Comment: I have an inspiron laptop with windows vista installed and it is working very good.

Comment: I am sure it does. :~) Try disabling 802.11n, Intel wireless cards/drivers have problems with it. To disable, run `sudo rmmod -f iwlwifi`, and `sudo modprobe iwlwifi  11n_disable=1`.

Comment: I can see the wireless available but with just one 1 brick. Not able to connect. Recently my n/w card had been replaced also.

Answer (score 1):

Easy do this in terminal, it will work:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
sudo modprobe -r b43
sudo modprobe b43
```

Voila, it works.

Comment: Worked for me on 14.04 as well. Thanks!